# How to make Laravel Model self aware of order

Tags: laravel, pagination

i need my Booking Model to hold the ID of the previous Booking in a timely matter, without using pagination of Laravel. I used paginate(1) before and orderBy('start_datetime') which worked nice.
The method i have so far also works, but only if the bookings all have different start_datetime.
If not, it will return the same previous ID in a loop when going backwards in the Bookings.
How can i define a unique, repeatable order of all Booking Models, which each model pointing to the previos model.

This is what my current function looks like:

```
public function previousBookingID()
{
$previousBooking = Booking::where('room_id', $this->room_id)
->where('id', '!=', $this->id)
->where('start_datetime', '<=', $this->start_datetime)
->orderBy('start_datetime', 'desc')
->select('id')->first();

return $previousBooking ? $previousBooking->id : null;
}
```

Comment: Using pagination would be the best solution since you will be able to tell when you need to stop without checking the null result.

Comment: instead of using `->select('id')->first();` you can use `->value('id'):` which will return the id value of the first result or null if there is no result.

Comment: Thanks for the ->value hint, but unfortunately i cannot use pagination :( I just need the previous Model ID

Comment: then it's better to use the skip method instead of using ids or star_datetime

Comment: @N69S Can elaborate what you mean ? Thank you for responding